# How can I use regex in Python to find these patterns

Tags: python, regex

Well I have a huge text and I need to find a way to catch a pattern and send it to a dataframe using pandas (that part is ok).

Basically it goes like this:

```
string = """ 
           Huge text etc etc etc
           Most frequent senders:

           NAME OF THE PERSON - 01.234.567/0001-89 (SOME RANDOM UPPERCASE TEXT) - 14 times in total of: R$10.000,00
           NAME OF THE PERSON - 012.345.678-90 (SOME RANDOM UPPERCASE TEXT) - 30 times in total of: R$10.000,00
           NAME OF THE PERSON - 01.234.567/0001-89 (SOME RANDOM UPPERCASE TEXT) - 10 times in total of: R$10.000,00

           Most frequent recipients:

           NAME OF THE PERSON - 01.234.567/0001-89 (SOME RANDOM UPPERCASE TEXT) - 14 times in total of: R$10.000,00
           NAME OF THE PERSON - 012.345.678-90 (SOME RANDOM UPPERCASE TEXT) - 30 times in total of: R$10.000,00
           NAME OF THE PERSON - 01.234.567/0001-89 (SOME RANDOM UPPERCASE TEXT) - 10 times in total of: R$10.000,00

           More text after this.  """
```

I need to separate the name of the person, the ID number (that can come in two different patterns: xx.xxx.xxx/0001-xx or xxx.xxx.xxx-xx), the number of times, and the total amount (BRL).

I managed to get the id numbers like this:

```
r = re.compile(r' [0-9]{3}\.?[0-9]{3}\.?[0-9]{3}\-?[0-9]{2} | [0-9]{2}\.?[0-9]{3}\.?[0-9]{3}\/?[0-9]{4}\-?[0-9]{2} ')

print(r.findall(string))
```

But that is it, I'm having difficulties trying to get the rest of the info correctly, any help would be very appreciated.

---

Text all together:

```
"""Huge text etc etc etc Most frequent senders: NAME OF THE PERSON - 01.234.567/0001-89 (SOME RANDOM UPPERCASE TEXT) - 14 times in total of: R$10.000,00 NAME OF THE PERSON - 012.345.678-90 (SOME RANDOM UPPERCASE TEXT) - 30 times in total of: R$10.000,00 NAME OF THE PERSON - 01.234.567/0001-89 (SOME RANDOM UPPERCASE TEXT) - 10 times in total of: R$10.000,00 Most frequent recipients: NAME OF THE PERSON - 01.234.567/0001-89 (SOME RANDOM UPPERCASE TEXT) - 14 times in total of: R$10.000,00 NAME OF THE PERSON - 012.345.678-90 (SOME RANDOM UPPERCASE TEXT) - 30 times in total of: R$10.000,00 NAME OF THE PERSON - 01.234.567/0001-89 (SOME RANDOM UPPERCASE TEXT) - 10 times in total of: R$10.000,00 More text after this.  """
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
^\s*([^-\n]+)\s+-\s+([-\d./]+).+\b(\d+)\s+times.+R\$([\d.,]+)$
```

See [**a working demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/B4XSDI/1/).

---

Broken down, this reads:

```
^\s*            # start of the line, whitespace
([^-\n]+)       # anything not a "-" nor a newline
\s+-\s+         # " - "
([-\d./]+)      # the ID part
.+              # every thing in that line...
\b(\d+)\s+times # ... backtracking to a digit, followed by spaces and "times"
.+              # once again every in that line...
 R\$([\d.,]+)   # ... backtracking to R$, followed by the total amount
 $              # end of the line
```

Note, that a name like `Jean-Baptiste Demartial` would break the rule. If you are likely to encounter such names, you may use

```
^\s*((?:(?! - ).)+)\s+-\s+([-\d./]+).+\b(\d+)\s+times.+R\$([\d.,]+)$
#       ^^^
```

instead. See another [**demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/hQPmTA/1).

---

In terms of `Python`, this could be:

```
rx = re.compile(r'pattern')

for match in rx.finditer(your_string_here):
    print(match.group(1)) # name
    print(match.group(2)) # ID
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, i'm new to regex so i have a follow up question, what is the correct way to use this pattern to get what i want? Is it re.compile(r'pattern')? And then what?

Comment: @GabrielAmarante: I have edited my answer, see the code snippet at the end.

Comment: Thank you very much for you time, if i'm not bothering, could you ask me one last question? Your pattern works if the text is formatted in the way i showed in the question, but i have some cases where the text is all together in one single line and the pattern does not work if that's the case. How can i get the informatiion in this case? I have edited the question to show you what i mean. Thank you in advance.